# Sonarqube Developer Cockpit Replacement

Tags: sonarqube

With Sonarqube no longer supporting Developer Cockpit I am in search of a recommended plugin to replace it with. Is there any other commercial or non commercial plugins that are intended to replace this?

I have not found any documentation or suggestions this far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's currently no replacement plugin.

From SonarSource perspective, it is planned to develop this set of developer-oriented features as part of SonarQube roadmap: https://www.sonarqube.org/roadmap/

Comment: Be careful when evaluating SonarSource claims.  They have a habit of saying they're going to do something and then not following through.  The gamification feature that was on the roadmap when this post was created has silently disappeared.